# IllegalFormatConversionException when trying to print input

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I am trying to scan input from the user and then print the input. However, I got the following error when I tried to run the code.

Erorr:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception IllegalFormatConversionException))
```

Code:

```
package dumb;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input value for variable i:");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Value for i scanned: %d",sc.next());
    }
}
```

Input:
    5

Why did I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: shouldn't you output `i` in the printf statement instead of scanning again?

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect the last line. You print something as decimal (`%d`) but you use `next()` instead of `nextInt()` (returning a `String` instead of an `int`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you get a String by `sc.next()` and with `%d` you say the program that it expects an integer.
So you have to change it e.g. to

```
System.out.printf("Value for i scanned: %d",sc.nextInt());
```

But i think you just want to print the first user input and not a second one. So you just have to print the value of variable i:

```
System.out.printf("Value for i scanned: %d",i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change sc.next to sc.nextInt. The reason being, %d indicates that you are going to display something which is a "decimal" aka number value. Sc.next gives you a string. %d cannot acceept a string data type.
Also, get rid of int i = sc.nextInt() because it is redundant.